# From where to remove "Welcome to the Frontpage"

Tags: php, joomla

i m developing one joomla site,,
i have assign one article to home page.

But the text "Welcome to the Frontpage" display in home page, and i can't get from where to hide it.

thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the second Google result for "Welcome to the Frontpage"](http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?t=200981)

> Go to Menus > Main Menu > Home > Parameters - System (on the right side) and modify 'Page Title'.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have your own default.htm (or default.html depending on site configuration)?

Normally the "Welcome" that you're seeing is a default page, that just gives you evidence that a site has been set up and is able to present pages.  Usually instructions for replacing the welcome page are provided in the page itself.

Comment: but is there any way to remove from joomla admin?
upto now i have removed it from code..
but this time i want to get rid of it...